# Moving several rectangles by dragging a single one in Monogame

Tags: movement, monogame

I am trying to make a simple card game in which the hand of cards is displayed on a row to the player on screen, and by dragging a single card, all others should move accordingly, with the same speed as the mouse on the X axis only. This is my current code:

```
public void HandleInput(GameTime gameTime)
{
    _previousMouseState = _currentMouseState;
    _currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

    if (_currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
    {
        _dragged = false;
    }

    _mouseDown = _currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed
        && _previousMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released;
}

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    foreach (Card card in _players[0].Cards)
    {
        if (_mouseDown)
        {
            if (card.Area.Contains(_currentMouseState.Position))
            {
                _dragged = true;
            }

            if (_dragged)
            {
                int movementDelta = _previousMouseState.X - _currentMouseState.X;
                Debug.WriteLine("previousX: " + _previousMouseState.X 
                    + " currentX: " + _currentMouseState.X);

                _players[0].Cards.Select(c =>
                {
                    Rectangle area = c.Area;
                    area.Offset(movementDelta, 0);
                    c.Area = area;
                    return c;
                }).ToList();
            }                
        }
        card.Update(gameTime);
    }
}
```

`HandleInput` runs before `Update` on the game loop. I have implemented a screen manager, but I don't think that is the issue, here. The thing with this code is that the mouse previous X, most of the time, is exactly equal to the current X, and movement is erratic at best (meaning that 90% of the time nothing happens, and the other 10% all cards move on a huge, uncontrollable leap). I have also tried using `gameTime` in the calculations for the movement delta, but that doesn't work, either. I'm not sure in what other way could I could tackle this (dabbled a bit on using `Vector2`, but unsuccessfully). I'm kind of noobish to Monogame, but I understand that polling is preferred to event handling here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually... The reason was that the event was triggering once per frame.

```
public void HandleInput(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        _previousMouseState = _currentMouseState;
        _currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

        if (_currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
        {
            _dragged = false;
        }

        _mouseDown = _currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed
            && _previousMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed;
    }


 public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        foreach (Card card in _players[0].Cards)
        {
            if (_mouseDown)
            {
                Point clickPoint = _currentMouseState.Position;
                if (card.Area.Contains(clickPoint))
                {
                    _dragged = true;
                }

                if (_dragged)
                {
                    _speed = new Vector2((float) ((clickPoint.X - _previousMouseState.Position.X) * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds), 0);
                    _players[0].Cards.Select(c =>
                    {
                        Rectangle area = c.Area;
                        area.Offset(_speed.X * 0.01f, 0);
                        c.Area = area;
                        return c;
                    }).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    //bleed out speed
                }
            }
            card.Update(gameTime, new Point(card.Area.X, card.Area.Y));
        }
    }
```

This way it works. However I would like to bleed out the speed over time, but that's another matter for another question.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods probably run at a frequency that's quite high so the differences between mouse positions are going to be small (or even zero since the position is an int). Instead of moving the cards for the delta distance between frames a better approach would probably be saving the cards' initial positions  when the mouse button gets pressed and then every frame check the current position to find the delta distance from the initial distance.